# How do I implement delete operation using AngularFireStore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to implement `DELETE` operation in an angular app. I want to be able to click a button and have a firestore doc deleted but my code isn't working. So I'm using a service for all my firestore operations and calling the service in my component

station.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { Station } from "../../models/station.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class StationService {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  deleteStation(stationId: string) {
    this.afs.doc("stations/" + stationId).delete();
  }
}
```

station.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { StationService } from "../services/station.service";
import { Station } from "./../../models/station.model";

@Component({
  selector: "app-station",
  templateUrl: "./station.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./station.component.css"]
})
export class StationComponent implements OnInit {
  stations: Station[];

  constructor(private stationService: StationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stationService.getStations().subscribe(data => {
      this.stations = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.data(),
          ...e.payload.doc.data()
        } as Station;
      });
    });
  }

  delete(id: string) {
    if (confirm("Confirm delete operation")) {
      //console.log(id);
      this.stationService.deleteStation(id);
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot find an id in my console.log message, it looks like this

```
address: "Somewhere along PTI road, Effurun. Delta State"
name: "Effurun"
region: "South-South"
```

How can i fix my code? Alert, this is my first time working with firestore.

Comment: "my code isn't working" is a bit broad. Does the `deleteStation` function get run? If so, does it pass the right `stationId` to Firestore? If so, is there any error shown on the developer console of your browser?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  `deleteStation` function does run since I get to see the console.log message but I don't see an Id. I call the deleteStation function in `station.component.html` like so `(click)="delete(station.id)"` There is also no error on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the bug. In `station.component.ts` ngOnInit() method, id was set to an object instead of an id. Set that to id like so

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.stationService.getStations().subscribe(data => {
    this.stations = data.map(e => {
      return {
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        ...e.payload.doc.data()
      } as Station;
    });
  });
}
```

Now an actual id of type string will be returned along with each object which can then be passed into `delete(id: string)` method.